# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when trying to filter data using linq

Tags: c#, datetime, iis

I am trying to filter data by date and the date format of the field is short date.
The dates I am filtering on thus looks like this example '16-12-2017'.

The query I am using looks as follow.

```
  data = data.Where(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d.InteractionDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= DateTime.ParseExact(filter.StartDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                     && DateTime.ParseExact(d.InteractionDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= DateTime.ParseExact(filter.EndDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

Examples

```
StartDate = "01-12-2017"
EndDate = "16-12-2017"
IntersectionDate = "20-06-2017"
```

On my local machine this works fine but when published to IIS I get the error.

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

How can I overcome this error?

Thanks

Comment: For starters, try using [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please show an example of the value inside the strings _d.InteractionDate_ , _filter.StartDate_ and _filter.EndDate_

Comment: Also, in order to provide an answer, how should the bad apples be treated? I assume they should be excluded by the predicate rather than included right?

Comment: I update the answer to show the examples of the string dates. Thanks

Comment: Timezone / date format settings different on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server the string is probably not formated like `dd-MM-yyyy` but differently. It is necessary to find out, how on the server the strings looks like.

The filtering could use e.g. function like `ParseDateTime` which will receive array of predefined formats so the code works with different formats on local machine as well as on server etc.

```
data = data.Where(d => ParseDateTime(d.InteractionDate, DateTimeFormats) >= ParseDateTime(filter.StartDate, DateTimeFormats) &&
                       ParseDateTime(d.InteractionDate, DateTimeFormats) <= ParseDateTime(filter.EndDate, DateTimeFormats))
                       .ToList();
```

E.g. the function will contain logging so when error occurs then the date time string can be found in the log file and the correct format can be appended to `formats` array used.

```
private static DateTime ParseDateTime(string dateTimeString, string[] formats)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dateStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, 
            formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
        return dateStamp;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, $"dateTimeString: '{dateTimeString}', '{string.Join(",", formats)}'.");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Example of how the predefined formats could look like. HTH

```
public string[] DateTimeFormats => new string[]
{
    "dd-MM-yyyy",
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "M/d/yyyy",
    "d.M.yyyy",
    "dd.MM.yyyy",
    "MM/dd/yyyy",
    "M/d/yyyy"
};
```

Comment: Thanks allot. Did get the error again but managed to get the correct format by logging the error :-)